# request two url node express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i would you like to request two url in node.js express. 
this urls are of this type:

```
app.get(/api/stats/:userId/, (req, res)..........)
app.get(/api/stats/seasonal/:userId/, (req, res)..........)
```

when I start my react application and I run axios on these two different urls and I store the result in two different tables, I get twice the same result: the data of the json file of the first link (/ api / stats /:userId /). 
queries are made on a stat method in which are included the two different links (see below). However, the two links correspond to two different data json. I search the answer to that everywhere for several days ... thank you for your help!

```js
module.exports = class RS {

  stats(userId, seasonal) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(!userId || typeof userId !== 'string') return reject(new TypeError('Invalid username'));
      if(typeof seasonal !== 'boolean') return reject(new TypeError('Seasonal has to be a boolean'));
      var endpoint = `https://r6stats.com/api/stats/${userId}`;
      if(seasonal === true){
        endpoint = `https://r6stats.com/api/stats/${userId}/seasonal`;
      }
      request.protocol(endpoint, (error, response, body) => {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == '200') {
          return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        } else {
          return reject(JSON.parse(body));
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

```js
app.get('/api/stats/:userId/', (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.params.userId;
    try{
        R6.stats(userId).then(response => {
            res.send(response);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        });
    }catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    };
});

app.get('/api/stats/seasonal/:userId/', (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.userId;
  try{
      R6.stats(userId, true).then(response => {
          res.send(response);
      }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
      });
  }catch(error){
      console.error(error);
  };
});
```

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: This post doesn't have any sign of proofreading, the poor grammar makes it really hard to understand.  
Also, the code is just thrown out without any explanation of what it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middleware order in Node.js matters. And therefore your second route is never executed, because the first one matches the URL.

Let's take a URL '/api/stats/seasonal/25' for example. It should execute second route right?

```
app.get(/api/stats/:userId/, (req, res)..........)
app.get(/api/stats/seasonal/:userId/, (req, res)..........)
```

But the first route gets executed, because 'seasonal/25' **is your `userId`**.
The second route never sees that.

Swap them, and if the optional is not matched, Node.js will check the next middleware.

```
app.get(/api/stats/seasonal/:userId/, (req, res)..........)
app.get(/api/stats/:userId/, (req, res)..........)
```